# Need help with regular expression

Tags: regex, string

Is it possible to have this done with one regex?

I need to match only those strings that have exactly one period/dot but the restriction is that that period/dot must not be at the end of the string.

Example:

```
abc.d will match

.abcd will match

abcd. will not match
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can do it in one regex:

```
^[^.]*\.[^.]+$
```

Comment: +1 - you made me learn a different and better way to write this regex!

Answer (score 3):

I really like @codaddict's answer, but how about something without Regex? ( C# code below )

```
if(a.Split('.').Length>2 || a.EndsWith("."))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("invalid");
    }
```

What I like is that it is much more clear that you don't want a string with two `.` and also a `.` should not be in the end. And this might actually be faster than using a regex.